# What does it mean for two field extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ to be "$\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic?"

Tags: field-theory, terminology, extension-field

I have seen this terminology in two texts and for whatever reason cannot find a source for what this means. Does this mean the two extensions are field isomorphic? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot find a source? Search stackexchange next time, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067132/f-homomorphism-between-two-field-extensions?rq=1).

Comment: Apologies. Understood if this question should be closed, but I spent a decent bit looking and didn't find anything.

Comment: No problem. I think one also has to get experience in searching. I found it rather quickly. You can try it next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two extensions of $K$ then they are called $K$-isomorphic if there is an isomorphism of fields $\varphi: L_1\to L_2$ such that $\varphi(k)=k$ for all $k\in K$. Equivalently, this means that $L_1, L_2$ are isomorphic as $K$-algebras.

Note that in the special case $K=\mathbb{Q}$ this just means there is an isomorphism of fields between $L_1$ and $L_2$. (since any homomorphism leaves the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed)